# Which is most recognised scrum master certification?

Tags: scrum

I am QA now, But, i wanted to have some sort of certification to add some weight to my resume.

I thought CSM would be one of the good certifications, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would favour either the CSM from the Scrum Alliance or the PSM from Scrum.org. They are both globally recognised and accepted.

nb: Full disclosure - I teach for both organisations.